# How do I get the instance of a mat-table?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm trying to get the instance of my table in order to use the renderrows() function when I update my dataSource.

I've tried doing it as I normally would've done it by using @ViewChild but no matter what I do it is undefined.

component.ts:

```
import {
  MatTable,
  MatTableDataSource,
  MatPaginator,
  MatSelectModule
} from "@angular/material";

@ViewChild(MatTable, { static: true }) playersTable: MatTable<any>;

addToDataSource(data) {
for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
  this.dataSource.data.push(data[index]);
 }
 this.playersTable.renderRows(); // this.playersTable is undefined.
}
```

.html:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table
   mat-table
   #playersTable
   [dataSource]="dataSource"
   *ngIf="!loadingData; else loading"
   class="row"
>
...
</table>
```

Comment: `static: true` -> `static: false`

Comment: If that doesn't work try `@ViewChild('playersTable',...`

Comment: Changing the static attribute didn't work and I'm not sure what you mean by '@ViewChild('playersTable',...'. I need to give the ViewChild a module to use (like MatTable, MatPaginator)

Comment: By passing a string, you reference the hashtag

Comment: Got it but sadly still undefined...

Comment: Already tried to get the instance reference in the afterviewinit hook function?

Comment: When are you calling `addToDataSource`?

[View queries are set before the `ngAfterViewInit` callback is called](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild), so it will be `undefined` if you try to access it before this callback.

Comment: I'm calling addToDataSource after the callback.
Also tried getting the reference in the  afterviewinit hook and nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give Id to your mat-table

```
<table mat-table #playersTable [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

And then using ViewChild you can access the instance  of table.
And Instead of pushing data to dataSource assign data with new MatTableDataSource()

```
  @ViewChild('playersTable', {static:true}) playersMatTable: MatTable<any >;
  addToDataSource(data){
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
     this.playersTable.renderRows();
   }
```

or if you want to add data to existing dataSource  then you need to refresh dataSource without using instance.

```
addToDataSource(data) {
  for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
   this.dataSource.data.push(data[index]);
  }
    this.dataSource = [...this.dataSource];  //refresh the dataSource
  }
```

Comment: Refreshing the dataSource like you said works wonderful and does solve my problem.
Though I still can't tell why I couldn't get the reference to the table itself.
Thanks!

Comment: As i said in first approach if you update datasource with new keyword then you will get  table reference .

Comment: What if I am giving an array (nested array) to data source dynamically then how can we refresh. Please let me know if you know